# Match words with specific backquoting combinations

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I need to match a word using regex, which lies between backquotes/backticks with 1 and 2 backquotes at most.

**Matching cases**

1. word should start with either one or two backquotes and ends with N backquotes
2. word should start with either N backquotes and ends with either one or two backquotes

**Should not match**

1. Word starts and ends with more than three backquotes

**Example**

`````````
I `need` to match a ``word`` from a ```sentence``
Which `lies`` between `backquotes```` and this ``should```` also match
and ```more``` than ```three```````` quotes ```````not```  matched
`````````

Matches:

1. need
2. word
3. lies
4. backquotes
5. should

**Attempt**

```
    Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("`{1,2}\\w+|\\w+`{1,2}", Pattern.DOTALL);
```

Comment: Why did you use `DOTALL` when the pattern doesn't even contain any dots?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use

```
(?<!`)`{1,2}\b(?!`)(.*?)\b`+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ma7fgT/2). Get the Group 1 value.

**Details**:

- `` (?<!`) ``  -  current location should not be preceded with a `` ` ``
- `` `{1,2} `` - 1 or 2 `` ` `` are matched
- `\b` - the word boundary requires the next char to be a word char
- `` (?!`) `` - the next char after 1 or 2 backticks cannot be a backtrick
- `(.*?)` - match and capture any 0+ chars (consider using `Pattern.DOTALL` to match across lines)
- `\b` - a word boundary, the next backtick should be preceded with a word char
- `` `+ `` - 1 or more backticks.

See the [Java demo](http://ideone.com/qV8LhZ):

`````````
String s = "I `need` to match a ``word`` from a ```sentence`` Which `lies`` between `backquotes```` and this ``should```` also match and ```more``` than ```three```````` quotes ```````not```  matched";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<!`)`{1,2}\\b(?!`)(.*?)\\b`+");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
while (matcher.find()){
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1)); 
}
`````````

Comment: @EduardoDennis: No, it [will work with quotes](https://regex101.com/r/j6VvVk/1), it won't work if OP wants to match strings that are not starting and ending with word chars. However, the current input suggests just that.

Comment: @EduardoDennis: I think OP  is using *backquotes* and *backticks* as synonyms.

Comment: Couldn't `\b(?!\`)` be simplified to `\w` (or maybe `[\d\p{L}]`) since word characters cannot be backticks? And since the OP is after single words wouldn `\w+` instead of `\b(?!\`)(.*?)\b` be sufficient?

Comment: @Thomas: Maybe, I assumed there may be more than 1 word and a 1 letter word is possible.

Comment: Hi @WiktorStribiżew,  How can we achive this case: word should start with either N backquotes and ends with either one or two backquotes

Comment: Hi, most probably [`\`++\b(.*?)\b\`{1,2}(?!\`)`](https://regex101.com/r/5jPDS3/2).

Comment: Maybe Thomas was right and you need [`\`+(\w+)\`{1,2}(?!\`)`](https://regex101.com/r/WINvaN/2)?